# Invoke apex method from custom button

Tags: apex, javascript

I am getting an error while trying to invoke an apex method which accepts a list as parameter  from custom button using javascript

**Error:**

> faultString "No operation available for request
>   {http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/package/PSS_deleteMilestoneAccessCheck}checkAccess,
>   please check the WSDL for the service."

**below is my apex class:**

```
global class PSS_deleteMilestoneAccessCheck {
    public static void checkAccess(list<PSS_Milestone__c> idsForDeletion){
    }
}
```

**This is my javascript:**

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")}
try{ 
    if({!$Permission.Can_Delete_Pss}){
        var pssOpportunity ='{!ParentObject__c.Id}'; 

        if(pssOpportunity!=null && pssOpportunity!=''){ 
                var result = sforce.connection.query("Select ID From ChildObject__c Where ParentObject__c = '{!ParentObject__c.Id}'", {
                  onSuccess : success,
                  onFailure : failure
                });

        }
    }
}
catch(err) { 
    alert('Something wrong happened'); 
}

function success(result) {
    var records = result.getArray("records");
    var idsForDeletion = [];

    for (var i=0; i<records.length; i++) {
        idsForDeletion.push(records[i].Id);
    }

    if(idsForDeletion.length != 0){        
        sforce.apex.execute("PSS_deleteMilestoneAccessCheck","checkAccess", {idsForDeletion: idsForDeletion});
        window.location.reload(); 
    }
}

function failure(error) {
    console.log(error);
}
```

I believe I am getting an error because of `sforce.apex.execute("PSS_deleteMilestoneAccessCheck","checkAccess", {idsForDeletion: idsForDeletion});`.Code works just fine if I remove this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please mark your "checkAccess" method as webservice and global. it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Make you controller method this way :

```
 global class MyClass {
      webservice static String MyMethod(){

         return 'test';
      }
    }
```